# How to change working directory in Rust without following symlinks?

Tags: rust, symlink

I have a symlink like so:

```
$ mkdir -p /tmp/foo/bar
$ ln -s /tmp/foo/bar /tmp/baz
```

If I now change the working directory to `/tmp/baz` with `std::env::set_current_dir`, I end up at the absolute path `/tmp/foo/bar`:

```rust
use std::env::{current_dir, set_current_dir};

fn main() {
    set_current_dir("/tmp/baz");
    println!("{:?}", current_dir().unwrap()); // prints "/tmp/foo/bar"
}
```

Is it possible to change the working directory so that `current_dir` returns the logical path `/tmp/baz` without resolving the symlink?

Comment: If you keep track of all links your program makes, you can loop and follow the links to see if any of them match your cwd

Comment: My program only navigates the filesystem, it doesn't create any links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::env::set_current_dir` calls the OS dependent implementation.

In the case of linux, which seems to be the one you're interested into, this calls [`chdir`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/chdir) whose behavior, defined by POSIX, involves solving the symbolic link.

The working directory can't be, by design, a link. It's a directory.

As `set_current_dir` only calls `chdir` which doesn't keep the trace of the link you gave it, the path you give is lost. If you want to store the path to the symbolic link file, you have to store it yourself in your user code.

Comment: It makes sense that the cwd can't be a link. I want to show the logical path in the UI of my program. I was hoping that I wouldn't need to manually keep track of the logical path, but maybe I'll have to do that then.

Comment: Yes, you have to keep the path. If it comes from some configuration you load, this configuration should be the source of its representation in your UI.