# How to get the current working directory in Rust if it is a symlink

Tags: rust, directory, path, symlink, working-directory

If there is a directory `/tmp/foo/bar` and a directory `/tmp/bar` which is a link to `/tmp/foo/bar` made with `ln -s /tmp/foo/bar /tmp/bar`, then if the current working directory is `/tmp/bar`, Rust's `std::env::current_dir` will return `/tmp/foo/bar` instead of `/tmp/bar`?

Is there a way to get the current working directory in Rust without resolving symbolic links?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70309794/how-to-change-working-directory-in-rust-without-following-symlinks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/93598), this is not really possible.

> For UNIX Rust just calls `getcwd()` and that behavior is documented in the [POSIX spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getcwd.html), so it will be the same on all conforming implementations.

From the linked spec:

> The pathname shall contain no components that are dot or dot-dot, or are symbolic links.

A possible workaround is to look at the `PWD` environment variable, but it's dependent on the shell to set this, and it's not a requirement that shells do so.  The executable may not have been invoked from a shell, either.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the question. I didn't `cd` into `/tmp/foo/bar`, I `cd`ed into `/tmp/bar`. If I run `pwd` it shows `/tmp/bar`.

Comment: @Austin Right, I just got the link and target backwards. I will fix that, but the rest of the answer is still valid. Or are you saying that Rust actually resolves the symlinks and returns `/tmp/foo/bar` as the working directory when it should be `/tmp/bar`? Because that would be really weird, and probably a bug.

Comment: Okay, but that doesn't answer the question. The question is that I want to get the path `/tmp/bar` in this scenario instead of `/tmp/foo/bar` and so how can I do that in Rust?

Comment: Right, yes. It seems like Rust is resolving the symlinks and I don't want it to

Comment: Ah, ok, then the wording of your question threw me off.  The part about "without resolving symbolic links" I parsed in a different way than you intended.  Let me try a few things and I will edit my answer.

Comment: @Austin Updated. Note that this question has been asked before for other languages (I found existing questions for PHP and Python) and the answer in both cases was about the same: you can't reliably determine this in a consistent way. I've been working on Linux for a good 20+ years and I only learned that `getcwd()` returns a canonical path today.

Comment: "the PWD environment variable, but it's dependent on the shell to set this," — and notice that this is because _it's the shell that tracks this concept at all_. As far as the kernel is concerned, the current directory is not a path at all, but rather a thing much like a file descriptor, pointing to a specific directory object in the file system independent of how that object is named.